# How to find a specific value in mssql?

Tags: sql, mssql-jdbc

I need to write query to find a specific value however that value should be the only value in the cell
Eg: If I'm using the like keyword to find "ort"
Cell 1 contains -> bqr ort abd 
cell 2 contains -> ort 
cell 1 should not be returned in the select statement only cell 2 even though ort is in cell 1.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Don't use `like` if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this out:

```
select* tablename from tablename where cell="ort";
```

If you still face any issue feel free to ask.